# applescript keystroke: right command and right control keys?

Tags: applescript

In Applescript, how can I send the keystroke for the right control key on the keyboard? How about right command key? Ultimately, I want to right-click in WINE ([winehq's FAQ explains that's not currently possible with ctrl+click](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX/FAQs)). But, it works great via KeyRemap4MacBook, although I need to send the right key.

```
tell application "System Events" to key code ???????
```

Answer (score 1):

For the right control it is:

```
tell application "system events"  
key code 62   
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

See Events.h or https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data.

The right command is supposed to be 0x36 or 54, but this didn't work for me:

```
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to key code 54
```

I also tried adding `__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::Q` to private.xml. `tell app "System Events" to key code 0` inserts `a` even if you change `a` to some other key with KeyRemap4MacBook.